# Is "[Countable noun] number" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

I know that "amount of [uncountable noun]" (e.g. amount of water) and "number of [countable noun]" (e.g. number of books) are what I should use. What I don't understand is that the "flipped" form of the former, "[uncountable noun] amount" e.g. water amount, sounds correct, but of the latter, "[countable noun] number" e.g. book number, sounds very wrong.

"The water amount has increased by 200ml" looks okay. "The book number has increased by 2" doesn't.

Is the latter structure really grammatically correct?

Comment: "Book number" sounds fine to me. Most nouns can be modified by most other nouns: if you search for *attributive noun* here, there are a lot of similar questions.

Comment: "Book number" suggests to me a number pertaining to a particular book, rather than a count of books (but perhaps that's because I'm a retired librarian!).  I don't find "water amount" particularly natural either.

Comment: I agree with @KateBunting. "book number 3" is like "edition number 3", "volume number 3", etc. The reason you can't use "book number" in place of "book count" is because we have this other sense of "number" and it takes precedence.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, and also thanks for suggesting "book count", because "book quantity" feels really stiff to me. If "water amount" also sounds unnatural (I lifted that from a news report I was reading), what would you suggest in place?

Comment: 'Water amount' should be 'amount of water' just as 'book count' should be 'number of books'. In fact, 'amount…' should really be 'quantity/volume of water' but that's about vocabulary, not grammar.